# MySQL Subqueries

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing an interesting problem.

Please see the picture of the two table I have.
userskill table 
[image]

Jobskill Table
[image]

What I want is 
I want to return the skill names of the userid 17 and the number of jobs in that skills. So the result should be something like this

```
Skill                                NumOfJobs
Advertising and Promotions Manger        2
Advertising Sales Agent                  8
```

Is that possible with one query or I should run two query?
Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT `skill`, COUNT(*) AS `NumOfJobs`
FROM `jobSkill`
INNER JOIN `userSkill` USING ( `skill` )
WHERE `userSkill`.`user`=17
GROUP BY `skill`
```

Basically this restricts your `userSkill` table to those rows, with `user` equal to `17`.

Afterwards, we take all those skills and join to `jobSkill` to get all jobs with the respective skill.

Finally using `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` we tell the database to count the entries per skill.

Comment: That is an awesome answer brother. It works. By the way, just to know is there any other ways to return? Thank you a lot.

Comment: "other ways to return" - what do you mean by that?